# How to come up with the Recursive solution for Leetcode Minimum Number of Refueling Stops

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I have been trying to implement the ***recursive solution*** for the [Leetcode Minimum Number of Refueling Stops][1]. I came up with the solution below but it doesn't pass all test cases. I have put so much effort into this. I would appreciate a support.
Here is my code so far:

```
    static int startTarget;
    private static int helper(int target, int currentFuel, int start, int[][] stations, Map<String, Integer> memo) {
        if (stations.length == 0)
            return currentFuel < target ? -1 : 0;

        if (stations[0][0] > currentFuel)
            return -1;

        String key = target + ", " + currentFuel;
        if (memo.containsKey(key))
            return memo.get(key);

        if (currentFuel >= target)
            return 0;

        if (start == stations.length)
            return -1;

        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = start; i < stations.length; i++) {
            int currentDistance = stations[i][0];
            int initialDistance = startTarget - target;
            int distance = currentDistance - initialDistance;
            int fuel = stations[i][1];

            if ((currentFuel - distance) >= 0) {
                int result = helper(target - distance, currentFuel + fuel - distance, i + 1, stations, memo);
                if (result >= 0 && result < min)
                    min = 1 + result;
            }

        }
        min = (min == Integer.MAX_VALUE) ? -1 : min;
        memo.put(key, min);
        return min;
    }

    public static  int minRefuelStopsBruteForce(int target, int startFuel, int[][] stations) {
        startTarget = target;
        int stops = helper(target, startFuel, 0, stations, new HashMap<>());
        return stops != Integer.MAX_VALUE ? stops : -1;
    }
```

Please I am only interested in the recursive solution.Thanks
[1]: https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-number-of-refueling-stops/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information wants to be free, so here you go :)

This solution uses the same approach as your solution, and it seems to work, so you can look at it to see what needs to be fixed with your code.

**Sadly it is way to slow**, so execution stops with "Time limit exceeded" at test case #115 that has approx 100 gas stations. So to solve the Leetcode task with recursion, a whole new way of thinking is needed.

```
public int minRefuelStops(int target, int startFuel, int[][] stations) {
    Integer result = helper(-1, startFuel, target, stations, 0);
    return result == null ? -1 : result.intValue();
}

private Integer helper(int currentStation, int currentFuel, int target, int[][] stations, int depth) {
    int currentPos = currentStation == -1 ? 0 : stations[currentStation][0];
    if (currentPos + currentFuel >= target) {
        return 0;
    }

    Integer best = null;
    for (int i = currentStation + 1; i < stations.length; i++) {
        int stationPos = stations[i][0];
        int stationFuel = stations[i][1];
        // Check out station that we have not yet passed && we can reach
        if (currentPos < stationPos && currentPos + currentFuel >= stationPos) {
            // Drive to station
            int fuel = currentFuel - (stationPos - currentPos);
            // Fill up gas
            fuel += stationFuel;
            // Continue
            Integer res = helper(i, fuel, target, stations, depth + 1);
            if (res != null && (best == null || res < best)) {
                best = res;
            }
        }
    }

    // Return "no can do" or return number of stations (adding *this* station)
    return best == null ? null : best + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close but there are some errors. For example, it does not make sense to check station[0][0] all the time (second if statement). And the HashMap should not be needed.

I wrote a solution that I think works, but I'm not sure you want it. I think you can solve this on your own, which is a lot more awarding. I suggest you start from scratch, and give it another try. Here are a few hints:

I think you can take these if statements away:

```
if (stations.length == 0)...
if (stations[0][0] > currentFuel)...
if (memo.containsKey(key))...
```

I think it is easier to follow the code if you don't change "target" (currently you subtract distance). Instead, add a parameter that tells "helper" how far you have travelled (distance).

Give it another try, I'm sure you'll make it. If not, let me know, and I'll post my code :)

Comment: Thanks so much. I’ll give it another try and let you know the outcome.